# Why was the maximum target set to 0xffff0000000...?

Tags: mining-theory, difficulty, satoshi-nakamoto

Is there any specific reason why the initial target was set to this:

```
00000000ffff0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Why not the maximum value for a 256 bit number:

```
ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I admit that I don't know for sure, but I have a guess.  Since Satoshi was mining by himself for the first blocks, he probably set the initial target to whatever would take approximately 10 minutes to mine a block on his CPU.  Had he set it to the maximum value for a 256 bit number, he would have mined the first 2,016 blocks almost instantly, and then immediately retargeted.

Because of the large number of blocks mined in such a short amount of time, this would likely have caused the retargeting calculation to produce a less-than-perfect result, meaning that the *next* 2016 blocks may be mined either far too quickly or far too slowly.

It was probably just better for him to initialize the target to a reasonable value, rather than force the algorithm to run its course in order to produce one.

Comment: The difficulty can only go up or down by a factor of four each time, so it would take 16 re-targets to get to difficulty 1. That would create a pre-mine of 1.6 million Bitcoins. (16*2016*50)

Comment: Yikes!  I was just thinking about how long it would take before stabilizing at a 10 minute block time.  I forgot about how many coins would be mined during that process.

Comment: Of course, it would have been possible to set the *initial* target different from the *maximum* target, to allow for the possibility for the target to go up or down from the initial value.  However, if the initial target was a reasonable number for one person's computer(s), there would probably be no point in allowing it to go higher, since that should never happen.